# Не получается использовать Windows.Data.Json

Tags: c#, json

Когда я пишу:

```
using Windows.Data.Json;
```

Компилятор выдает ошибку:

```
CS0246  Не удалось найти тип или имя пространства имен "Windows" (возможно, отсутствует директива using или ссылка на сборку)
```

NET4.8

Это мне нужно для:

```
JsonObject root = Windows.Data.Json.JsonValue.Parse(jsonstring).GetObject();
```

Comment: `Windows.Data.Json` - это для UWP проекта, если у вас не он (WinForms/WPF/Console и др.), то используйте альтернативы (`System.Text.Json` если переведете проект под современный .NET, либо один из популярных NuGET пакетов `Newtonsoft.Json`). Если же у вас UWP проект, то смотрите какие .DLL подключены в вашем проекте.

Comment: .NET Framework 4.x устарел. Пишите сразу под .NET 5, там есть `System.Text.Json`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена.

Просто использовал Newtonsoft.Json:

```
dynamic json = JObject.Parse(jsonstring);
```

За ответ спасибо @EvgeniyZ:

```
Windows.Data.Json - это для UWP проекта, если у вас не он (WinForms/WPF/Console и др.),
то используйте альтернативы (System.Text.Json если переведете проект под современный.NET,
либо один из популярных NuGET пакетов Newtonsoft.Json).
Если же у вас UWP проект, то смотрите какие .DLL подключены в вашем проекте.
```

Comment: Каким именно образом решена проблема?

Comment: @aepot Просто использовал Newtonsoft.Json


`dynamic json = JObject.Parse(jsonstring);`

Comment: Напишите это в ответе